# "of in a half century of critical hyperbole over all things Arendt"

Tags: meaning

*But Hannah Arendt accomplishes something rare in any biopic and unheard **of in a half century of critical hyperbole over all things Arendt**: it actually brings Arendt’s work back into believable—and accessible—focus.*

Source: http://www.theparisreview.org/blog/2013/05/30/lonely-thinking-hannah-arendt-on-film/

Could you explain to me the bold passage from the bellow excerpt that praises the movie about Hannah Arendt. Does the "critical hyperbole" mean the way how the director treats the life of HA? And what about "Arendt things"?  Is this phrase related to all biographies (in movies or in literature) dedicated to HA that have been made in the last 50 years?

Comment: "Is this phrase related to all biographies (in movies or in literature) dedicated to HA that have been made in the last 50 years?" -- even more so: the phrase refers to everything said or written about Hannah by critics.

Comment: "Things Arendt" –   I miss the preposition there ("of" or "about").But I don't presume that the sentence is in any sense wrong.

Comment: **unheard of**.  A man leaping higher than 5 meters! That is unheard of!  **hyperbole over** .... hyperbolic accounts of;  **all things Arendt** anything and everything having to do with Arendt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But *Hannah Arendt* accomplishes something rare in any biopic and
>   unheard of in a half century of critical hyperbole over all things
>   Arendt: it actually brings Arendt’s work back into believable—and
>   accessible—focus.

```
But [the work entitled] *Hannah Arendt* accomplishes something 
   (which is) rare 
        in any biopic  
   and 
   (which is) unheard of
        in a half century of critical hyperbole
             over all things Arendt...
```

**rare** and **unheard of** are parallel. To be **unheard of** is never to have been experienced or witnessed before.

**all things Arendt** :  any matter, tidbit, story, etc relating to Arendt.
["The discussion is wide open -- *all things Mozart* are fair game: his travels, his compositions, his romantic involvements, his relationship with his father, anything having to do with him."] The modifier there follows the noun it modifies:  ~"all Arendt things".

**over** = concerning, about.  "What's this argument *over*?"

Every aspect of Arendt's life, no matter how small or trivial, has been exaggerated in critical accounts for the last half century. *Hannah Arendt* accomplishes something which was not witnessed in those accounts and which is rare in any biopic...